# Active Directory Authentication Universal Windows Application

Tags: c#, active-directory, win-universal-app

Is there a way to authenticate through AD without having Azure AD in a `Universal Windows Application`? In Web Applications i use this methodology

```
 using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

 using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my.domain"))
 {
       bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password); 
 }
```

This is how I authenticate users through AD(not Azure) in my Web Applications. Is there a similar way this can be done in a Universal Windows Application?

I have found a package called:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
```

But it looks like that requires Azure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We currently authenticate the same way that you're used to - on the WebApi back end.  As far as I know, you cannot communicate directly with AD from the app.